Enviar archivo de audio con api mediante ajax
Necesito poder enviar un archivo de audio "wav" o "mp3" mediante una api  en ajax, no puedo usar FormData() ya que me aplicación no me lo permite.
Estas lineas me dan error " Requested key of a value that is not an object".
Un saludo y gracias.
Este es el error que me da:
{
    "status_code": 422,
    "message": "[{'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('body', 'file'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': None, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/missing'}]",
    "data": null
}


Código
var token = theRoot.varToString("TOKEN");
var uuid = theRoot.varToString("UUID");
var path = theRoot.varToString("PATH");
var url = theRoot.varToString("URL");
var token = "Bearer "+token; 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': token,
        'Accept': '*.*',
        'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
        'accept':'application/json',
         },
     
    

    // Aquí deberías enviar datos en formato JSON, si es lo que requiere el servidor
    data: { file:  { type: "audio/wav", path: path}},
   
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        theRoot.setVar("DATA", JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    
        alert(jqXHR);
        theRoot.setVar("DATA", JSON.stringify({
            status: jqXHR.status,
            statusText: jqXHR.statusText,
            responseText: jqXHR.responseText,
            error: errorThrown
        }));
     }
});


Hola. ¿Ese mensaje es la respuesta de la API? ¿Dónde lo recibes, en la parte error o en la parte success de tu petición Ajax? Convendría que depures lo que estás enviando, con algo como console.log({file:  { type: "audio/wav", path: path}}); verificando lo que muestra eso en la consola. Al parecer los datos están llegando nulos.

a parte de enviar el { type: "audio/wav", path: path}}), tambien debes de enviar el archivo, si lo envias en un json el archivo deberia de estar en base64:{ type: "audio/wav", path: path,file:"una cadena super larga en base64"}})

Ese mensaje me lo da el alert(jqXHR) que tengo en el error, el archivo tiene que ir en formato .wav o mp3 no acepta otro formato. Lo tomo de path que es la ruta de mi pc

¿Depuraste lo que estás mandando en el parámetro data? ¿Qué muestra? Si he entendido bien, la API se ocupa de crear el archivo de audio a partir de la URL que le mandas?

Dejo la solución aquí, comentar que la variable path es la que tiene la ruta al archivo. Asi me ha funcionado correctamente. Un saludo y muchas gracias
var path = theRoot.varToString("PATH");
    var url = theRoot.varToString("URL");
    var hea = theRoot.varToString("HEA");
    var token = "Bearer "+token; 
    
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
       headers: {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization":token,
           },
      data: {
        file: {
          type: "file",
          path: path  // Cambié las barras invertidas por barras normales
        }
      },
      responseType: "text",  // Este campo no debe estar en 'data', sino en la configuración de la petición
      success: function(data, http_status) {
         theRoot.setVar("DATA", data);
      },
     error: function(xhr, http_status) {
        if (http_status === 0) {
            alert("No se pudo conectar con el servidor. Verifica tu conexión o revisa el CORS.");
        } else {
            alert("Error: " + http_status);
            alert(xhr.responseText || "No hay respuesta del servidor.");
        }
    }
    });

